# Can I use localhost URL as notify_url in paypal IPN?

Tags: paypal

Can I give my localhost url in paypal IPN to send the message back to notify and process it?

OR...

Do I need live server URL to process (I guess this is right) because paypal knows live url when sending the message, but it never knows localhost url to send message.

Can anyone please tell me, do I need live server url or can I use localhost because I am not sure.

If I need live URL, how can I debug and develop my functionality (to send mail etc) in visual studio?

Does anyone have a small example or some useful links??

Comment: You need a URL that can be accessed from other networks as well.

Comment: not clear, lets consider if i have http://192.168.0.100/myapp which can be access using any machine in LAN, but ofcourse not on internet if it is not LIVE IP.

Comment: what is your view about this????

Comment: No you can not unless your port is open and people can reach it from outside world.

Comment: Hey, shahzeb, i like to give your post as useful. Consider your's as an answer as well.,, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, notify_url must be directly accessible via the internet,  because PayPal will POST the data to it.
In addition, it must run on port 80 or 443. Other ports are not allowed.

Comment: Robert, I found yesterday after posting these question, you are right and i would like to say "thank you very much", at least other will not waste their time to try locally.

Comment: @Amitpatel, while it would be nice, it should have been pretty obvious due to what you were doing here. If you wanted however, and had a static IP address, you could have always host your own local server for testing.

Answer (score 16):

You may try it locally. Use https://ngrok.com/ to access localhost from internet.

ngrok is a command line tool and ngrok 80 command will assign a domain name in the following format :
http://s1ab334.ngrok.com and the https:// version is also the same.

Now, you can use the url in ipn simulator.